# Symfony Doctrine-fixtures bundle, fail --purge-with-truncate

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony, fixtures

Im using DoctrineFixturesBundle and trying to load fixtures

```
app/console -e=test doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

All data in postgres database.But why after --purge-with-truncate table sequence not restart, and just incriment with each fixture load?
How i read in postgres truncate documentation

```
RESTART IDENTITY
Automatically restart sequences owned by columns of the truncated table(s).
```

May be entities generated incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT SETVAL((SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('person', 'person_id')), 1, false);
```

replace `person` with the *table name* and `person_id` with the *serial field(column) name*.

More details here http://timmurphy.org/2009/11/19/resetting-serial-counters-in-postgresql/